# TSX + React: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined at Menu.handleClick

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I am using typescript@2.6.1 and react and react-dom @15.6.2.

I can't seem to debug this issue:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined  at Menu.handleClick.
This is at `this.setState( (prevState) => {`

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Monaco from './Monaco';
import shiftOverlayButtons from '../common/shiftOverlayButtons';

export interface Props {

}

export interface State {
    isOpen: boolean;
}

export default class Menu extends React.Component<Props, State> {

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
    }
    public state: State = {
        isOpen: false
      };

    public render() {
        return <button id="overlay-btn" className="menu-btn" onClick={this.handleClick}></button>
    }

    public handleClick(): void {
        this.setState( (prevState) => {
            if(prevState.isOpen === false){
                this.openMenu();
                return {
                    isOpen: true
                };
            }
            else {
                this.closeMenu();
                return {
                    isOpen: false
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private openMenu(): void {
        shiftOverlayButtons(true);
        ReactDOM.render(<Monaco/>, document.getElementById("overlay"));
    }

    private closeMenu(): void {
        shiftOverlayButtons(false);
        //ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById("overlay"));
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Menu/>, document.body);
```

PS: When I do `this.handleClick.bind(this)` I get another error: GET file:///Users/kalpa/Desktop/monaco-sample/vs/loader.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND ... I am using webpack @3.8.1

Answer (score 2):

Prefer using an arrow function for handlers. Change

```
public handleClick(): void {
```

to

```
public handleClick = (): void => {
```

## More

Arrow functions: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the bind at handle click. So from

```
onClick={this.handleClick}
```

to

```
onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
```

Reformated Code:

```
handleClick(event) {
    this.setState({isOpen: !isOpen}).then(()=>{
        if(!this.state.isOpen){
            //do something when false
        } else {
            // do something when true
        }}}
```

Comment: When I do that I get another error: GET file:///Users/kalpa/Desktop/monaco-sample/vs/loader.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND ... I am using webpack @3.8.1

Comment: You also have incorrectly used the function setState. it takes an object you are sending a function. If you want to use a function after the setState you can do so by using setState({prevState: prevState}).then(yourfunction);

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you write an answer?